# View xml with html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to view all xml content, but I get only 3 element from each array , and I want to view all arrays contents.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
    <!--
    - Structure schemas
    -->
    <pma:structure_schemas>
        <pma:database name="makes_data" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
            <pma:table name="Sept2014">
                CREATE TABLE `Sept2014` (
                  `Year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Make` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Trim` varchar(73) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Engine Size` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Engine Cylinder` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Engine Compressor Type` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `Transmission` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
            </pma:table>
        </pma:database>
    </pma:structure_schemas>

    <!--
    - Database: 'makes_data'
    -->
    <database name="makes_data">
        <!-- Table Sept2014 -->

<table name="Sept2014">
            <column name="Year">2001</column>
            <column name="Make">Acura</column>
            <column name="Model">RL</column>
            <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan</column>
            <column name="Engine Size">3.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type"></column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>
        <table name="Sept20141">
            <column name="Year">2001</column>
            <column name="Make">Acura</column>
            <column name="Model">RL</column>
            <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan </column>
            <column name="Engine Size">3.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type"></column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>
         <table name="Sept20142">
            <column name="Year">1254</column>
            <column name="Make">Acurattttt</column>
            <column name="Model">RL</column>
            <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan </column>
            <column name="Engine Size">3.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type"></column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>


        </database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","tt.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;




x1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("database");



for (var i=0; i<x1.length; i++){
  x=x1[i].getElementsByTagName("table");
  for (var j=0; j<x.length; j++){
      x2=x[j].getElementsByTagName("column");
      for (var k=0; k<x.length; k++){
          document.write(x2[k].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("<br>");
      }
  }

}






</script>
</head>
<body >



</body>
</html>
```

I get this and I don't know why it shows only 3 element of every array.

2001
Acura
RL
2001
Acura
RL
1254
Acurattttt
RL

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner for loop (`for (var k=0; k<x.length; k++){` is wrong. It uses `x.length` instead of `x2.length`. The fact that you had three nodes on the higher level was a hint. ;-)

With better naming, you won't make mistakes like this so easily, or at least they are easier to spot. Even if you don't want to change `i` to `tableIndex`, you can still make it easier by at least choosing an appropriate one-letter name, that matches the properly named other variables:

```
var databases = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("database");
for (var d = 0; d < databases.length; d++){
  var tables = databases[d].getElementsByTagName("table");
  for (var t = 0; t < tables.length; t++){
    var columns = tables[t].getElementsByTagName("column");
    for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++){
      document.write(column[c].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. If you use x2.length it view the first table complete but not the rest of tables.